# Почему моя программа не выводит result?

Tags: c++, калькулятор

Написал я свою первую в жизни программу, при этой чуток еще изучил все функции.

Почему когда ввел две цифры в калькуляторе и выбрал знак для операции, программа не выводит result?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
int age = 0; 
int name = 0; 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); 
cout « "Добро пожаловать в калькулятор от Вячеслава Левахова! " « endl; 
cout « "Введите пожалуйста возраст. " « endl; 
cin » age; 
cout « "Введите пожалуйста ФИО. " « endl; 
cin » name; 
if ( age < 18 ) 
{ 
cout « "Ваш возраст слишком мал.И вы еще в состоянии считать в уме простые числа. Всего вам наилучшего !" « endl; 
} 
else { 
cout « "Вы успешно прошли регистрацию. Приятного вам пользования" « endl; 
} 
double a, b, result; 
char n; 
cout « "Введите a" « endl; 
cin » a; 
cout « "Введите b" « endl; 
cin » b; 
cout « "Выберите одну из данных операций. А именно знак ." « endl; 
cout « "Сумма + " « endl; 
cout « "Вычитание -" « endl; 
cout « "Деление /" « endl; 
cout « "Умножение *" « endl; 
cin » n; 
if (!strcmp(&n, "+")) 
{ 
result = a + b; 
cout « "Сумма a+b =" « result « endl; 
} 
if (!strcmp(&n, "-")) 
{ 
result = a - b; 
cout « "Разность a-b =" « result « endl; 
} 
if (!strcmp(&n, "/")) 
{ 
result = a / b; 
cout « "Деление a/b =" « result « endl; 
} 
if (!strcmp(&n, "+")) 
{ 
result = a * b; 
cout « "Произведение a+b =" « result « endl; 
} 


return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Замените эти `!strcmp(&n, "+")` на простые `n=='+'` - у вас же просто `char`, а не строки.

Comment: На будущее, прикладывайте код в таком виде, чтобы мы могли его скопилировать. А то у вас тут `«` вместо `<<`.

Comment: так может поэтому оно и не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Замените эти `!strcmp(&n, "+")` на простые `n=='+'` - у вас же просто `char`, а не строки.

На будущее, прикладывайте код в таком виде, чтобы мы могли его скопилировать. А то у вас тут `«` вместо `<<`.